# MSSQL Bulk Loader using pentaho data integration

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, bulkinsert, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I am currently using pentaho data integration and i need to use MSSQL Bulk Loader Job entry to insert record from a file that is in my local to the remote server. Seems like it is not working.

I currently get this error:

> > Cannot bulk load because file "\sharing\datasync\data\orders.csv" could not be open. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied)

Will need an advice on the execution for the flow as i myself am kinda new in using Bulk insert/bcp

Comment: You'll need to expand on "not working". What exactly are you doing and how is it not working. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hi Nick, actually i am importing a file into a table in database where the source file is in another server and will need to use bulk insert to complete the data loading fast. So far, i've created a shared folder and upon running bulk insert query, i got this error "Cannot bulk load because file "\\sharing\datasync\data\orders.csv" could not be open. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied)

Comment: I will edit the question and add that - in future please put the error in in the first place. Never write "not working". I guess Pentaho runs under a service account and I guess that service account doesn't have access to that folder... or you have it open in excel

Answer (score 1):

Import and export the data using BULK insert and BULK import to process the data

**Example**

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
   FROM '\\computer2\salesforce\dailyorders\neworders.txt';  
GO
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi Vasanth, thank you for sharing, so basically i need to use a shared folder to place the file and then run the bulk loader?